# Measuring time using an STM32F407VGT6 microcontroller

Tags: stm32, timer, linux, rtos, chibios

I'm using a custom board for charging and testing batteries. 
Its 'brain' is an STM32F407VGT6 microcontroller. 
I'm developing in Ubuntu (14.04.2 LTS), using ChibiStudio (ChibiOS/RT 3.0 development branch and Eclipse Kepler). 
While in charge mode, I need to see how much time has passed since I initially started charging the battery. I'm having trouble with writing the necessary steps required for the time measurement. The microcontroller has an internal real-time clock (RTC). It also has timers. And ChibiOS has a time measurement function. However, I went through the documentation, researched online, but I still cannot make it work.

Comment: Share code for what you tried.  Best if you make it minimum code to show your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I added two header files inside main.c:

```
#include "chrtclib.h"
#include "rtc.h"
```

Secondly, in the makefile of the project, immediately after these 2 lines,

```
# C sources that can be compiled in ARM or THUMB mode depending on the global setting.
CSRC = $(PORTSRC) \
```

I added this:

```
$(CHIBIOS)/os/various/chrtclib.c \
```

And, finally, I used two functions (from the ChibiOS RTC time conversion utilities) where I needed them inside main.c:
`rtcGetTimeUnixSec(&RTCD1)` and `rtcSetTimeUnixSec(&RTCD1, unix_time)`